# Twitter Boostrap Menu - drop on hover? An issue in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So, I've pretty much completed my newest project utilizing Twitter Bootstrap and I'm going about fixing some issues that are buggining me, and I can't for the life of me understand why I piece of code is working on FF but not in Chrome so I was wondering if you guys can help me out a bit...

Mainly, I'm using the following to allow dropping of menus by hover, not click.
https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown

Can someone give me a bit of direction as to why it's not working in Chrome?

The site is: http://www.savamarkovic.com/dal/index.php/?lang=dal

Comment: I received this error via console. `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown/master/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: In the FF, it shows `ReferenceError: options is not defined $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdownHover(options);`. Sure that there should be settings where there are "options"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub doesn't want files to be served from raw.github.com, so the MIME type is text/plain, which is preventing it from loading in Chrome...try including the script locally in your project.

Comment: That was the issue in did. I forgot to include it locally after testing something! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you can achieve a clean dropdown on hover using this simple css block:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

This will save you the overhead of using an extra js plugin and it works in all browsers. Bonus: clicking on the main menu item will lock the dropdown open, per the standard implementation of the bootstrap dropdown.